# is it correct to say "as per your comfort" or "at your comfort"

Tags: abbreviations, shorthand

I find saying/writing,

"As per your convenience"

And

"At your convenience"

too lengthy, cumbersome, etc.

Therefore, is it correct to say "as per your comfort" or "at your comfort" ?

Comment: Could you please give some more context. What is the interlocutor meant to do "at /as per their comfort"?

Comment: Did you try to research the phrases that you want to use? You could search in Google Books, for example, to see whether and how published authors tend to use those phrases.

Comment: _As per your convenience_ sounds very odd to me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ***at leisure***:

> when you want to and when you have time to:
>
> - You can take the documents home and study them ***at (your) leisure***. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/at-your-leisure))